# how to add if current date is before a certain date condition as an if-statement parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement

I have a WordPress site and I have written a filter:

```
function wc_add_string_to_price_newline( $price, $product ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    if ($product_id == '1190') {
        $price .= "<br>(15% off until May 31, 2020)";
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wc_add_string_to_price_newline', 10, 2 );
```

I want to add a second condition to the if-statement: if current date is before 5-31-2020.  How can I add that current date condition as a second if-statement parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($product_id == '1190' && date('Y-m-d') < '2020-05-31') {
    $price .= "<br>(15% off until May 31, 2020)";
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing strings as if they were numbers, compare them as int's: `time() > strtotime('2020-05-31 23:59:59')`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson any reason for this? String comparsion works great.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Both this answer and the comment by @MagnusEriksson work but with a slight change: the `>` must be changed to a `<`.  If you update your answer I will mark it as the solution.  I did originally say after but it was a typo.

Comment: This is a special case where lexicographic comparison is equivalent to chronological order. You should explain why.

Comment: @fall3n oh sorry, I haven't noticed that.. first time I read "after date" (instead of before) for some unknown reason, I edited answer :)